# Dynamically set asp.net login password requirements

Tags: asp.net, login-control, non-alphanumeric

I have multiple companies using my website. A few of them are complaining that their customers can't understand what a non-alphanumeric character is (though we give examples in bright red letters) and want us to ease our password requirements. We're willing to acommodate those who ask, but don't want that to affect those who are happy with the added security.

I know I can remove the non-alphanumeric character requirement totally in web.config, but I don't want to remove it for everyone, just for specific sets of users.  Is there a way to set the requirment for a login control dynamically in my login page, in Page_Load or something similar?